# jquery ajax Display multiple pages in div from multiple selection drop-down form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a multi select drop down. I need a div to be filled with pages based on the selections. I have this working for one selection at a time. I need it to also work when I select more than one option the corresponding pages will populate the div.

For exemple... if I select Item1 and Item2. I want the pages item1.php and item2.php displayed in my div. If I then delete item1 from the selection (using chosen.js) I need only item2.php to show since that is the only current selection.

Here is my current code:

```
 $('#maindiv').on('change', function(event) {
      var selected = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/'+ selected + '.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { cat: selected },

        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#displaydiv').html(data)
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });

  });
```

Comment: so what is your problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3gnzrmt2/). You can't get any output from here but you have to use this in your server.

For more clarification about the page is get or not, see this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3gnzrmt2/1/). Here you can see the page which will load.

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#maindiv').on('change', function(event) {
            $('#displaydiv').html("");
        selected = $(this).val() + "";
        arr = selected.split(",");
        i = 0;
        $(arr).each(function(){
            $.get('includes/'+ arr[i] + '.php', function( data ) {
              $('#displaydiv').append(data);
            });
            i++;
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple id="maindiv">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<div id="displaydiv">

</div>
```